# jquery use plugin on dynamic content

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create an image gallery from an rss feed with the galleryview plugin. When the html content is statically in the page the plugin works but when I generate the html dynamically from the rss feed calling the plugin seems to do nothing. Here is the code I'm using:

```
function getScrollerContent() {
    $.get('photos.rss', {}, function(xml) {
        var contentHtml = '';
        var filmStripHtml = '<ul class="filmstrip">';
        $('item', xml).each(function(i) {
            contentHtml += '<div class="panel">';
            var imgSrc = $(this).find('image').text();
            contentHtml += '<img src="' + imgSrc + '" />';
            contentHtml += '<div class="panel-overlay">';
            contentHtml += '<h2><a href="' + $(this).find('link').text() + '">' + $(this).find('title').text() + '</a></h2>';
            contentHtml += '<p>' + $(this).find('desc').text() + '</p>';
            contentHtml += '</div>';
            contentHtml += '</div>';
            filmStripHtml += '<li><img src="' + imgSrc + '" /></li>';
        });
        filmStripHtml += '</ul>';
        contentHtml += filmStripHtml;

        $('#photos').append(contentHtml);
    });

    $('#photos').galleryView({
        panel_width: 800,
        panel_height: 300,
        frame_width: 100,
        frame_height: 100
    });


}

$(getScrollerContent);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The get call is asynchronous so you need to add the call to `galleryview` at the end of the callback function in your `get` as `get` returns immediately and then `galleryview` is called (on an empty div):

```
$.get('photos.rss', {}, function(xml) {

    // rest of your code here

    $('#photos').galleryView({
      panel_width: 800,
      panel_height: 300,
      frame_width: 100,
      frame_height: 100
    });
});
```